# PHPUnit test error csrf Laravel, en gitlab CI/CD docker

Tags: php, laravel, test, gitlab, phpunit

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de escribir peticiones POST en los test de integración, en la maquina en local donde lanzo los test estos pasan sin problemas, pero en el contenedor docker de gitlab fallan por el token csrf, aunque ponga el token en la petición sigo sin pasar el test, es un poco estraño.

Tenia entendito que este middleware se dehabilitaba en los test, pero ya no se que pensar.

Error

```
Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException: 

.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:71
```

Código test

```
public function testClientStatusUpdate()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $user = \App\User::find(1);

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/client/2/status', [
        'status' => 1, 
        '_token' => csrf_token()
    ]);
    $response->assertStatus(302);

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/client/2');
    $response->assertViewIs('client.show');
    $response->assertSuccessful();
    $response->assertSee('Estado cambiado correctamente correctamente.');
    $response->assertSee('<span class="label label-success">Activo</span>');
}
```

CI/CD

```
image: php:latest
services:
  - mysql:5.7.24
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: project_name
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/
  - node_modules/

before_script:
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev  libxml2-dev libbz2-dev libpcre3-dev -yqq
  - docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo_mysql curl json intl gd xml zip bz2 opcache
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  # Run  build
  - php composer.phar install 
  - cp .env.example .env
  - php artisan --version
  - php artisan key:generate
  - php artisan config:cache
  - php artisan migrate --force
  - php artisan db:seed --force

test:
  script:
  - php vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
```

Otros datos:
Laravel: 5.5.44 
PHPUnit: 6.5.13

**¿Hay alguna forma de desactivar el middleware `VerifyCsrfToken` para los test o de escribir los test de forma que se obtenga un token válido para que pase la prueba?**

Comment: Nunca he usado laravel, así que espero que esto te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772335/disable-laravel-5-not-5-1-middleware-for-testing